Can I get a help on grid layout?
I'm learning CSS now and I'm struggling to get it to work the way I want and I can't figure out why, here is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        header {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-areas: "logo . btnusr btnlogoff";
        }

        .logo {
            grid-area: "logo";
            height: 35px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .btnusr {
            grid-area: "btnusr";
            height: 35px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/921x222" alt="logo" class="logo">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" alt="btnusr" class="btnusr">
    </header>
</body>

</html>

I'm trying to make it so I get the logo on the top left, a blank cell of 11fr, and the other 2 buttons on the right side.
I'm defining the grid-area to the specific places but, no matter what I change the objects doesn't move to the desired location. Even if I swap the grid-area from logo to btnusr the logo is always first and the button is always being placed in the second cell, here is a print of the grid view in the browser:


grid-area: does not require/want quotation marks. so grid-area: "logo"; should be grid-area: logo; https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rNgNYyr

Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

You've done everything right except you've used quotes where they don't belong. For example, you should use grid-area: btnusr; rather than grid-area: "btnusr";


body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        header {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-areas: "logo . btnusr btnlogoff";
        }

        .logo {
            grid-area: logo;
            height: 35px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .btnusr {
            grid-area: btnusr;
            height: 35px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
<header>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/921x222" alt="logo" class="logo">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" alt="btnusr" class="btnusr">
    </header>




It works! Can you believe I spend at least 3 hours looking to css code on the internet and I couldn't see that I missplaced the quotes?! Ty very much duude.
Both answers works but I guess that your answer fits better to my usage. Ty very much!

I would rather use display flex and space between:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

      header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .logo {
        height: 35px;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .btnusr {
        height: 35px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/921x222" alt="logo" class="logo" />
      <div class="buttons">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" alt="btnusr" class="btnusr" />
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" alt="btnusr" class="btnusr" />
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>


"you need to have the same amount of elements as you defined in the template columns" — no, not so. Two elements in the HTML is fine. It's the way the way the grid areas are cited in the CSS that's the problem.

It works but, as ralph said, it was not working because of the missplaced quotes, fixing it also solves the issue I was having. Ty for your time trying to help!

I see you edited your code, and it really seems to work better. I'm trying to understand it. How does the browser knows that the buttons are supposed to be on the right? Is it because they are inside their own div?

Exactly, without the div one button would be in the middle, with the div it puts space between the img and the div, forcing them to the sides
